# Move down the content inside a minipage to align the neighborhood

Tags: align, minipage

I had defined this command in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\pf}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Proof.}}\quad\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{\textwidth}\footnotesize #1\end{minipage}}
```

And in document, there is a line used this command:

```
\pf{$\begin{alignedat}{2}
B_{(Y,d)}(a,r)&=\big\{x|x\in Y\wedge d(x,a)<r\big\}=Y\cap\big\{x|d(x,a)<r\big\}\\
&=Y\cap\big\{x|x\in X\wedge d(x,a)<r\big\}=Y\cap B_{(X,d)}(a,r)
\end{alignedat}$}
```

The output is:
[image]

How can I move down the content in the minipage? The wanting result is like:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want a proof without any word?

Comment: @egreg This will not be published. Just my note. :-) Also, this is easy enough, so even no words is fine.

Comment: `$\begin{alignedat}[t][2]...\end{alignedat}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}`, but I'm not really sure you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\newcommand{\pf}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Proof.}}\quad\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{\textwidth}\footnotesize #1\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\pf{$\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
B_{(Y,d)}(a,r)&=\big\{x|x\in Y\wedge d(x,a)<r\big\}=Y\cap\big\{x|d(x,a)<r\big\}\\
&=Y\cap\big\{x|x\in X\wedge d(x,a)<r\big\}=Y\cap B_{(X,d)}(a,r)
\end{alignedat}$}

\pf{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get

```
Overfull \hbox (56.08862pt too wide)
```

for every `\pf` appearance.

---

A better definition for your `\pf`. The `minipage` around the environment is used to avoid page breaks in a proof, but I don't think it's really necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\newlength{\proofwd}

\newenvironment{pf}
 {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \settowidth{\proofwd}{\textbf{\textit{Proof.}}}%
  \begin{itemize}[labelwidth=\proofwd,leftmargin=\dimexpr\proofwd+\labelsep]
  \item[\textbf{\textit{Proof.}}]\footnotesize}
 {\end{itemize}\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pf}
$\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
B_{(Y,d)}(a,r)&=\{x\mid x\in Y\wedge d(x,a)<r\}=Y\cap\{x\mid d(x,a)<r\}\\
&=Y\cap\{x\mid x\in X\wedge d(x,a)<r\}=Y\cap B_{(X,d)}(a,r)
\end{alignedat}$
\end{pf}

\begin{pf}
\lipsum[2]
\end{pf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the fixes in the math formulas: `|` should become `\mid` and there's no need for `\big`; in any case it should be `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}`, if you feel the braces should be larger.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if using something like `\settowidth{\proofwd}{\textbf{\textit{Proof.}}}` and  `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-\proofwd}` is proper?

Comment: @Eric That might be an alternative. But the `itemize` version can be more easily adapted if you want to get rid of the `minipage`.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is it a typo that your code still have a `minipage` environment? If we use an `itemize` to do so, is `minipage` then omitable?

Comment: @Eric Not if you want that proofs stay on the same page